# Nontrivial external automorphism in a nonstandard model of set theory

Tags: set-theory

I am currently studying NFU, and I've got a problem, which in fact is a ZFC-problem. I refer to M. Randall Holmes's paper "The set-theoretical program of Quine succeeded, but nobody noticed". Page 9, second paragraph, the author wrote : "We show how to construct a model for NFU directly. Work in a nonstandard model of set theory which has an external automorphism $j$ and an ordinal $\alpha$ such that $j(\alpha) >  \alpha$. This gives us a model of TTU with a shifting automorphism, determined by $\alpha$, $j(\alpha)$, $j^2(\alpha)$,..." I understtod the proof below, with the construction of a model of NFU. But my problem is : how can we obtain a nontrivial external automorphism in a nonstandard model of (say) ZFC ? My first idea was : OK, since the model is non standard we can find an ordinal $\alpha$ and an infinite sequence $(\alpha_n)$ such that $\alpha_0=\alpha$ and $\alpha_{n+1} \in \alpha_n$ for each $n$. Then , we decide that $j(\alpha)=\alpha_1$, $j(\alpha_1)=\alpha_2$, etc, and define $j$ inductively by $j(x)=\{j(y) : y \in x\}$. But this does not work, since the model is illfounded, so we are not sure that the transfinie induction will succeed. Can someone give me a short explanation for this phenomena, or at least a good reference ? Thanks by advance. Best regards. Martial Leroy

Comment: In fact, not every ill-founded model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ has an external automorphism! Some do, but others *(e.g. ill-founded pointwise-definable ones)* don't.

Comment: Can't you do something like this?  Use Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski to get a model of ZFC generated by a set of indiscernibles of order type $\mathbb Z.$  Then define an automorphism of this model by mapping each indiscernible to the next one in order.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Mitchell : sorry, but can you tell me which Ehrenfeucht-Mostowski result you are referring to?

Comment: @MartialLeroy It’s a construction of models (of a given theory) with indiscernibles of any desired linearly-ordered order type. The proof is based on Ramsey’s theorem. Indiscernibles were used in an essential way by Silver in his development of $0^\#.$   There’s a very brief intro at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Mostowski_theorem

Comment: @Mitchell Spector : OK, thanks. I only knew the version of this theorem which allows infinitely many indiscernibles. Now I've got to read the paper which is cited on wikipedia.

Comment: @MartialLeroy   I should probably expand on the automorphism. You’d add Skolem functions to your language, and get a model of ZFC + the Skolemization axioms which has a set of order-indiscernibles of order type $\mathbb Z$ (these indiscernibles are ordinals in the model, but they’re externally non-well-founded). Then take the Skolem hull of the set of indiscernibles. That’s the model $M$ you want.  [continued…]

Comment: [… continued] Each member of this Skolem hull can be written as a term $\tau(i_1, \dots, i_n)$, where $i_1, \dots, i_n$ are from the set of indiscernibles. So the map that takes each indiscernible to the next one in order can be naturally extended to a map from all of $M$ to itself. That map is an automorphism because of the indiscernibility property.

Comment: I haven’t written all this out in detail, but I think it works. Also, I apologize for any typos; I’m writing this on my phone.

Comment: @Mitchell Spector That's really clear, now. Special thanks for all these efforts with your phone...

Comment: @MitchellSpector Very nice answer! Should this be posted as an answer on the original question?

Comment: @C7X Thank you! I don’t have the time to write it now unfortunately, but hopefully the comments give enough info to anyone who’s interested.